# Android Google cloud vision API get Json and use Json to go to another acitvity

Tags: android, json, vision, google-cloud-vision

Basically in the title, I've been trying to work with the Google Cloud Vision API through android as I'm trying to make an application that will allow the user to scan the name of a game for instance, and the app will detect the name of the game or object and then move to an activity or web page that corresponds with the name given back in the JSON. Only problem is, I'm unable to get the JSON in the android application and I'm not sure why, I heard that its not possible on the android app but I'm not 100% sure on that. I was wondering if anyone would be able to confirm if thats the case or if there are any alternatives to my solution as I'm starting to tear my hair out over this.

Comment: Put your code :)

Comment: Also have a look at https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: @NovoLucas I've tried looking at that, but I find myself quite lost in trying to navigate where everything needs to go. Especially when it talks about setting up authentication. I'm not sure where anything needs to go in regards with that. As for the code that I've been using  I haven't really gotten too far out in the code.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/android/README.md Mainly been fiddling around with that to see if I can do anything, haven't made any changes really so what is here is what i've been looking at.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the complete string of the JSON just get the:

```
BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = annotateRequest.execute();
```

and then:

```
System.out.println(response.toString()); //this will print the JSON
```

Comment: response.toString() will return some protobuf string serialization, not json. To get json use: com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat.printer().print(response)